# How to update two $scope properties together

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I do not know why `$scope.result` does not update when `$scope.countDown` change and how to fix it?. Please help, thanks

SCRIPT:

```
angular.module('mean.system').controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', 'Global', '$timeout', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, Global, $timeout, $http, $location) {

        $scope.countDown = 10;  
        $scope.result = $scope.countDown;  
        var timer = setInterval(function(){
            $scope.countDown--;
            $scope.$apply();
        }, 1000);  

        console.log($scope.result);

    }]);
```

HTML:

```
<section data-ng-controller="HeaderController">
    <div> my time: {{result}} </div>
    <div> your time: {{countDown}} </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a watch if you want them to udpate together:

```
$scope.$watch('countDown', function(newVal) {
  $scope.result = newVal;
});
```

`$scope.result = $scope.countDown;` just gives `result` a one-time value of the current value of `countDown`. It's just like with any other variable. For example, `var a = 'abc';` You wouldn't expect that to update, right? It's just setting a variable to a value.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't update because you don't update it.

Just do it:

```
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        $scope.countDown--;
        $scope.result = $scope.countDown;
        $scope.$apply();
    }, 1000);
```